# How to remove title bar in windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

IDE: Visual Studio 2010 c# .net, Windows form application

Hi,
I am trying to remove the title bar in windows form application but I am not able to do it.   ( Image is here):

Title Bar:

[image: http://i772.photobucket.com/albums/yy9/yogeshkmrsoni/titlebarProblem_zps57e6a986.jpg]

for removing it, I have tried this code:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

but it still  showing me the border like shown in image.

Answer (score 2):

try setting Forms ControlBox property to false and Text property to empty string ("").

here's a snippet:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
this.Text = String.Empty;
```

and you can retry setting the FormBorderStyle to none this way
[image]

Comment: @sportingmindztech: so please submit your source code or debug logs(if you are getting some kind of errors) so we can pin point the exact problem.

Comment: @sportingmindztech: where.? and one more thing I would like to ask is that what platform you are the building for , because the TitleBar is different than the standard title bar.?

Comment: Windows7, visual studio 2010

Comment: @sportingmindztech: just try adding this code `this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;` to you constructor in spite of the `_Load` function. Just below the `InitializeComponent();` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be just fine:

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
```

You may also do the following:

```
this.ControlBox = false;
this.Text = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't to code. Just set `FormBorderStyle` of your form to `None`. It completely removes title bar, borders, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
this.ControlBox = false;
this.Text = "";
```